# How to set the column width of a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

Can anyone tell my how to set the width of the columns of a SharePoint list?

I want to prevent the user from resizing the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot restrict the users from resizing the column width in list view.

Also, as per my observation, if someone changes the width of the column in list view, it will be changed for the particular user only. It will not affect the list view for other users.

View for **User 1**:

[image]

View for **User 2**:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I have created a list a long time ago in Classic view and made the columns not resizable. Now I want to make the same list in the new view.  But I can not make the columns not resizable.

Comment: Yes, you cannot restrict the users from resizing the column width in modern experience. Is there any problem with resizing the column? I think even if they resize the column, it will change it for them only and not for other users.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification